# Building and deploying works, but not running

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

When I try to deploy or build a report, I am able to succesfully. There are no errors.

However, when I try to run it locally, I am getting:

[image]

I would be most grateful on advice on where I can start in order to troubleshoot this issue?

I am running SSRS 2008 in Visual Studio 2008 on windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: How is your data source set up?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thank you for your msg. it's set up for windows authentication. i tested the connection and it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use linked server and windows authentication my first guess would be to check if your SQL Server service account is a domain user and if it is - check if it is set up properly in AD.

link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/08/10/694657.aspx

But then again, i'm not very good at guessing things :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same user login for both? If not check that the user has the access the the data source.

Also it seems the local pc doesn't have the OLE DB driver installed. I got a reverse situation at work where my pc had the driver but the server didn't.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks! where do i get the oledb drive and how can i be sure i dont have it?

Comment: It comes with the SQL Server feature pack, check http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=16978 or http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/default.aspx

Comment: how can i be sure i dont have it?

Comment: Dont know to be honest... check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113860/how-to-check-if-an-oledb-driver-is-installed-on-the-system

Comment: MS has this... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721219(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: hey! i think i figured out whats wrong. there'a server that has a provider called PervasiveOLEDB.11.0 and connecitng works from there! do you know how i can get this same provider?

Comment: try http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/920a0817-d9b8-4766-b0bf-baa6430acf93/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try http://forums.asp.net/t/1383105.aspx/1

Seems like some kind of grant is needed for the linked server operation locally that is probably already present in production, I thought this bit was promising:

```
GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO MachineName\ASPNET
GRANT ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER TO MachineName\ASPNET
```

Comment: thanks so much.  i will try this. can you please tell me what does asp.net have anything to do wiht it?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '\'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '\'.